# Do we need both ephemeris and ephemerides tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag

I just noticed that we we have both [ephemeris](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ephemeris) (35 questions) and [ephemerides](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ephemerides) (6 questions) tags.

I can't see how the six questions that have ephemerides need it, and I'm guessing that ephemeris is all we need, but I could be missing something.

Comment: shameless plug for my English SE question [How to pronounce “Ephemerides”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370655/217285)

Comment: Pretty sure we don't need both, but not sure which the community thinks should take precedence, so I'll wait to see what answers we get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, I think we only need "ephemeris". I'd prefer the singular being the merged tag, as plurals going from "-is" to "-ides" are not the most familiar words outside of technical contexts (to the point where users with >20k reputation need to ask about how they are pronounced!).

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'll wait 24 hours, and if there's no opposition then I'll do the merge.

Comment: Merge complete.